# How Spring Hystrix helps when one microservice data requires in other microservices?

Tags: spring, hystrix

Hystrix helps for false tolerence and latency tolerence.By using fallback method we can show empty data or some message that that service is down, but if  MicroService1 id needs in other business logic how to handle this?

MicroService1-Here is my Sample Code

---

This is the API which will be called by Other microservice2. Its Needs to return one String as ID.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
    public String list() {
        return "Some Id";
    }
```

### Microservice2- Calling MicroService1 API

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.timeout.enabled", value = "true"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "500"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "fallback.enabled", value = "true")

    }, fallbackMethod = "fallback", commandKey = "list", groupKey = "EmployeeServiceImpl")
    public String list() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.getForObject(microservice1apiurl, String.class);
    }

    public String fallback() {
        return "";
    }
```